# jQuery $.post fails in Chrome with data not empty. NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, post, xmlhttprequest

Here is the code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.post('/save/', {a : '1'}, function(res){
        $('#random').html(res);
    }, 'text'
).error(function(jqxhr, status, err){
    $('#random').html(err);
});
```

In Chrome, sometimes return **"Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"**, However, sometimes are OK.

If I use **empty** data, like 
    `{}`
or 
    `[]`
or 
    `""`

it always works, and in Firefox 5, it also seems to always work!

I tried different data format, like `({data: '111'})`  and simply string `"&a=1&b=2&c=3"`, but still the same thing.

My backend is kind of simply:

```
@csrf_exempt
def save(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            message = 'POST' + str(datetime.utcnow())
        else:
            message = 'GET'
    else:
        message = 'NOT AJAX CALL'

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

- Webserver is Django's local development server (manange.py runserver 8000)
- My chrome is 14.0.797.0
- My jQuery is 1.6.1
- Windows XP
- Python2.5

additional info:
In fiddler, the response error is:

```
ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

Comment: Which version of Chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NETWORK_ERROR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235929/network-error-xmlhttprequest-exception-101)

Comment: @James   Chrome version is 14.0.797.0

Comment: I just found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868059/django-webkit-broken-pipe/3971012#3971012